# USB device stopped working

Tags: windows, usb, windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

My USB just stopped working. Yesterday it worked properly and now it doesn't work at all. I cannot open files or anything.

**Symptoms:** When I plug my USB devise in any of the USB ports on my PC, it appears in MyComputer as `Removable Disk (F:)`. However, when I try to open it, it says `Please insert a disk into Removable Disk (F:)`. When I plug out the device, it disappears from MyComputer.

**What I've tried so far:** I've already tried a lot of things. Here is what I had tried, but nothing of that worked:

- I opened command prompt and typed `F:`. But, instead of navigating to the `F:` volume, I got error message: `The device is not ready.`
- Opened `DeviceManager` and I uninstalled all devices under `Universal Serial Bus Controllers` and then rebooted the PC. Windows installed all drivers again, but the USB still doesn't work. I also checked for drive updates and it says that drivers are up to date.
- Tried using `DISKPART.exe` (open command prompt and type `diskpart` - it is a native Windows' program). Then I typed `list disk` and it listed my USB as Disk1, but here is the output: `Disk 1 | No Media | 0 B | 0 B`. It says "No Media". Then I typed `select disk 1` and `list partition`, but the output is `There are no partitions on this disk to show.`
- Tried to format the disk. Right click on `F:` from MyComputer and select `Format` from the context menu. The message says: `There is no disk in drive F:. Insert a disk, and then try again.`
- Tried using HxD disk editor. Unfortunatelly, it doesn't even recognize my USB.
- Tried using ActiveUndelete and ActiveDiskEditor, but they both say `Unable to open physical disk: Not Ready. Not initialized.`
- Tried to write a C++ program to access the disk. The function call `CreateFile("\\\\.\\F:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);` actually returned a valid handle, but calls to `WriteFile` and `ReadFile` failed with code `0x15 - The device is not ready.`
- Tried to troubleshoot the USB hardware using Windows' troubleshooter. After scanning, it says: `No problems found.`, but it also displays a warning: `Hardware changes might not have been detected.`
- Tried using Windows's Disk Manager. It displays `F:` disk, but says `No Media`. When I right click on it and select `Properties`, it says `This device is working properly.`
- Tried to change drive letter (as suggested on MSDN forum). I tried all letters and I restarted computer after each letter, but nothing worked. So, I switched back to `F:`
- Tried to open it from Chrome (navigate to `file:///F:/`), but I got the error `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`
- Tried other ports on my PC, tried restarting computer, tried a lot of other things, but nothing seems to work.

**Question**

What may cause the problem? Is my USB device dead or does it smell more like a software problem? Is there something I haven't tried yet? Thank you in advance if you decide to help :)

---

<sup>**Some details:** I have all administrator privileges on my PC and by default all programs start with administrator privileges. Everything worked yesterday and I have no idea what is causing the problem now. I currently don't have another PC to test the USB on, and I also don't have another USB to test on my PC, so it is hard to tell what is actually causing the problem. USB is not physically damaged, so I hope the bug is on software level. My operating system is Widnows, I don't have Linux bootable CD currently so I cannot test if it works using another OS or PC. I have to fix my usb as soon as possible, because I have very important data on it. Thank you in advance.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the USB device is dead. You can try reading it using other computers to verify that you get the same symptoms.

Comment: It is very weird for a USB to completely die over night. Yesterday it worked perfectly fine and fast. Unfortunately, I cannot test it on other computers (at lest not in the next three days), but I need the data from it as soon as possible. Probably I'll wait for other answers while hoping that you are wrong :'(